# Cant understand data source section of a given connection string

Tags: sql-server, database-connection, connection-string, localdb, sql-server-2016-localdb

I have the following connection string and I am trying to make sense of it:

```
Data Source=(localdb)\.\DB;Initial Catalog=DB12;Integrated Security=True;Persist Security Info=False;Connect Timeout=60;Encrypt=False;Current Language=English;
```

The bit I am trying to understand
Data Source=(localdb).\DB;Initial Catalog=DB12

(localdb)  ==> Is this the instance of sql server or the machine name? 
.\        ==> Local machine name?
DB         ==> a folder in local instance of local sql server?

Initial Catalog=DB12  ==> The name of the database?

What difference would it make if I change above connection string to

```
(localdb)\.\DB   ===>  .\DB
```

Comment: `Initial Catalog=DB12` does indeed mean the database name you are connecting to is `DB12`

Answer (score 0):

`(localdb)` refers to the "[localdb](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-express-localdb?view=sql-server-ver15)" lightweight SQL Express installation that is installed with Visual Studio and with "SQL Server Express with Advanced Services", the `\.\` means that the connection string is trying to connect to a shared instance of LocalDB - in this case one called "DB"

And the initial catalog does refer to the database it will initially be using when connected - so this connection string translates as

> connect to the shared instance "DB" of LocalDB and the database called "DB12" in that instance.